# how to convert .tib fille to .vhd/.vmdk

Tags: virtualization, acronis, conversion

I#ve been looking for ways to convert a .tib file to a .vmdk file, however all solutions i was able to find on the topic rely on old discontinued software that i can no longer find online (for example acronis true image 2014, or vCenter standalone converter).
are there any alternatives for what i am attempting to do? even if i can only convert the .tib file to a .vhd file i would be happy since the conversion from .vhd to .vmdk is not as problematic.
any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the way to do it myself, used acronis true image 2018 to convert the .tib file into .vhdx files, then used virtualbox in the windows cli to convert from .vhdx to .vmdk files the  way it is described in this article
https://www.fabozzi.net/convert-vhdx-to-vmdk/
and was able to boot in virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

1: Create a New VM with the Hard Drive Size you want.

2: Create a Shared Drive on your VM or a Secondary VMDK that has your TIB file on it, this is so your rescue media can get access to it.

3: Boot the VM using your mounted Acronis rescue media.

4: Restore the image to your Newly Minted VMDK that you created in Step 1.

5: Now you have your VMDK do with it as you desire.

Have fun with your brand new super exciting VM.